# Iterating of Generic Collections in Java

Tags: java, loops, generics

I'm very new to Java and struggling to understand generics, the ways they can be used, and the syntax for doing so.

I've the following class

```
class MyCustomArray<T>{

    private T[] myArray;

    // Default Constructor
    public ArraySet(){
        this.myArray= (T[]) new Object[10];
    }

    // Method to get array length
    public int getSize(){
        return this.myArray.length;
    }

    ... some random code

    // Method to iterate
    public void iterateSomehow(MyCustomArray<? extends T> collection){

        // doesn't work
        for(T obj: collection){...}

        // doesn't work
        for(int i=0; i< collection.size(); i++){
            T nextObj= collection[i];
        }

    }
}
```

This is for a class assignment, which disallows the use of standard classes like `ArrayList`. I feel like I'm missing something *fundamental* here, but don't know what.

Is my approach wrong? Is it just syntactical?

Some more context:

My immediate goal is to check each value in the given `collection` object as such (psuedo-code, clearly):

```
for( int i=0; i < collection.length; i++ ):
    value = collection[i];
    if (value == badValue):
       // whatever
```

Comment: What about `for(T obj: collection.myArray){...}`?

Comment: @Sweeper Wow. That's exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: @Shevtsov I had a typo in my code: the `(R[])` should have been a `(T[])`. Am I ok approaching this way?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was wrong, you can do this(with T). Here is example of custom generic list https://www.ambrishontech.com/2018/02/23/create-custom-generic-arraylist-in-java/ (Item is like T in your code)

Comment: @Shevtsov No worries, the typo was my fault! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only arrays can be indexed with the `[]` syntax, and only arrays or classes implementing `Iterable` can be used in the right hand side of an enhanced for loop (`for (T xxx : yyy)`). Your class is not an array and does not implement `Iterable`, so neither of your attempts worked.

Your class contains an array though - `myArray`. You can just iterate through that. Both of these are fine:

```
for(T obj: collection.myArray){...}
// or
for(int i=0; i< collection.getSize(); i++){
    T nextObj= collection.myArray[i];
}
```

I also feel like your method should not have the parameter and should iterate over `this` instead (if this is actually a requirement of the homework, then it can't be helped):

```
for(T obj: myArray){...}

for(int i=0; i< getSize(); i++){
    T nextObj= myArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate though collection directly(because it's just object) you should access to myArray. You also can implement Iterable interface, it's allows you something like this

```
  for(T obj: collection){...}
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-implementing-iterator-and-iterable-interface/